# How to translate facebook time in my locale

Tags: facebook, time

facebook returns this value for publish date:

```
2012-05-17T05:07:43+01:00
```

How do I translate it to human readable date/time in my location, for example I'm in hongkong?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the programming language your using …

In PHP for example you could use `strtotime` first to get an unix timestamp from the above time string, and then format it with `strftime`.

Comment: thanks for you response, btw yeah im using php... i'm gonna try your suggestion..:)